# How can I use "helvetica 67 medium condensed" font in my iOS app

Tags: uifont

I have added the font file name in my plist and used its name in the code but still this font is not showing up. I have attached the font file also.
When I am logging the Helvetica font family, I can see these fonts
**"Helvetica-LightOblique",
Helvetica,
"Helvetica-Oblique",
"Helvetica-BoldOblique",
"Helvetica-Bold",
"Helvetica-Light"**